# Import google contacts into a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, import, google-api, google-contacts-api

I want to import google contacts into my rails app.

First of all how dare Google didnt include a sample code for Ruby here,

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/?csw=1

Second of all,

If you use omnicontacts, https://github.com/Diego81/omnicontacts, it wont fetch the phone_number, city, country and other things(only first_name and last_name)

Third,

This solution is a bit famous if you do the googling, http://rtdptech.com/2010/12/importing-gmail-contacts-list-to-rails-application/ it wont work for me.

Fourth,

It was easy to import google calendar events with omniauth gem, with the following good piece of code,

```
def action_after_callback
# After authenticating and hitting callback redirect url, which will route to this action.
@auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
#Use the token from the data to request a list of calendars
@token = @auth["credentials"]["token"]
client = Google::APIClient.new
client.authorization.access_token = @token
service = client.discovered_api('calendar', 'v3')
@result = client.execute(
  :api_method => service.events.insert,
  :parameters => {'calendarId' => 'primary'},
  :body => JSON.dump(event),
  :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
p @result.data
end
```

API DISCOVERY is not available for contacts I heard from googling.

So someone help me whats the best way?

Answer (score 0):

For fetching all contacts you can use this gem.

```
https://github.com/aliang/google_contacts_api
```

For fetching a single contact you have to create your own service. Anyway, it's pretty easy to create it upon the gem which i've mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should prefer two gems

```
gem 'contacts'

gem "omnicontacts`
```

This is very easy to use.

Reference url: "https://github.com/cis-sourabh/gmail-contacts"

Comment: OP has already mentioned that omnicontacts "wont fetch the phone_number, city, country and other things(only first_name and last_name)".

Comment: Yea, omnicontacts was very easy but didn't import phone numbers, which is very weird and doesn't solve the problem